# I can not install apps from Fdroid but I can not see any error

Tags: fdroid

I have problem with my Fdroid because I can not install any app from it.

I tried rebooting my smartphone and reinstalling the application. Additionally, I made sure to grant all the necessary permissions available. However, despite these efforts, I am still encountering an error related to F-Droid.
[that is all what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fp1w.png)